# Download Image and Update TableView cell asynchronously using a category without using any library

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

We have SDWebImage library that provides that provides a category(UIImageView + SDWebcache.m) for image downloading, caching and it also sets each correctly on UITableView or UIColllectionView cell. I don't want to use any library and want to create a similar category. Once the image is downloaded, how do I keep track of the cell for which this image belongs and see if the cell is visible or not to avoid setting the image on another indexPath which has reused the cell. The code that I have written(caching logic is removed here):

```
// Inside the category, I have this method
-(void)SetThumbImageFordownloadURL:(NSString*)url {

    [MyDownloadManager asyncImageDownload:url withProgressHandler:nil andCompletionHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSUInteger errorCode){

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //if cell is not visible and is reused by another index, this image wil be set on wrong cell
            [self setImage:image];
        });

    }];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Keep a reference to the URL inside the cell as a property, and nil it out on reuse method.

and in your code block, return the actual URL for the image, and do something like this:

```
 [MyDownloadManager asyncImageDownload:url withProgressHandler:nil andCompletionHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSURL *url, NSUInteger errorCode){

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //check if current hold key is equal to url and only then set the image.



            [self setImage:image];
        });
    }];
```

Option 2/finetune: Add a cancel method to your "MyDownloadManager" , and cancel the current download in "didEndDisplay" method of your tableview/collectionview.

Comment: @Sneakw Wiith this approach I see a problem. TableView or Collection View will have multiple cells visible at a time. So, when image for URL1 is downloaded, we could have started downloading the URL 10 image, assuming we have 10 images visible in collection view at a time. So, downloadImage URL won't match the url provided in the category method and image won't be set on the cell even if it is visible.

Comment: @DeepArora The block runs the correct cell if you run it inside the datasource methods willDisplay or cellForRow, but do you run this outside the methods then you must loop visible cells everytime you receive a image which is not good practice for this.